# Localhost suddenly becomes 'loS'?

Tags: bash, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running a node app on a Rasperry Pi (Raspian) and I have seen this error happen twice now.  Out of seemingly nowhere we will see error logs fill up with the following:

```
You have triggered an unhandledRejection, you may have forgotten to catch a Promise rejection:
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'hub_user'@'loS' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:$
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:103:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:537:20)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
    at /opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:106:18
    at Promise._execute (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300$
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.$
    at new Promise (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
    at Client_MySQL.acquireRawConnection (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:104:12)
    at Object.create (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:231:16)
    at Pool._createResource (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:326$
    at Pool.dispense [as _dispense] (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-poo$
    at Pool.acquire (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:392:8)
    at /opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/lib/client.js:281:19
    at Promise._execute (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300$
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.$
    at new Promise (/opt/data/Hub/node_modules/knex/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
```

When connected via SSH to that device (when it gets into this state) if I type the following:

```
mysql -uhub_user -p
```

It will try to connect as 'hub_user'@'loS'.  If I specify 'hub_user'@'localhost' it will append the 'loS' after localhost.

Does anybody have any idea where this is coming from?

Comment: Well that's the hostname bit, so the contents of `/etc/hosts` output of `hostname` (or `hostname -f`) and whether any hostname-mangling services are running (networkmanager, or possibly DHCP client software, or multicast DNS servers?)...